# php: why 14 + ' ' + 12 returns 26?

Tags: php, string, casting, numbers

I'm a beginner in PHP. with my experience something like "number + String + number" should be a string.

But apparently, it's a number in php.
in my case:

```
echo 14 + ' ' + 12;
// returns 26
// expected: "14 12"
```

why did this happen?
and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding a '+' for adding two numbers. These are not a string so it will do a addition.
Use this if you want to add these couple of number as a couple of string :-

```
echo '14'.' '.'12';
// result "14 12";
```

You can also use with a html code for a blank space :

```
echo '14&nbsp12';
// result "14 12";
```

Answer (score 0):

Because echo accepts parameters only inside quotes. If you want text being returne use:

```
echo"14 12";
```

In you case PHP does 2 things

1. Takes 14 adds to 12
2. Concatenates space.